# how to run git clone locally

Tags: node.js, git, github, git-clone

I am new to git and i want to know how to use git repo. generally developers created for use our own.
jus like i want to use any node.js example code : [Git Repo Link](https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes) and i have clone it by git-bash also i have download the .zip file in my local computer. but dont know what is the next step to make it runnable. i want to learn from the code people done on git. i have run

```
npm install
```

and after downloading all dependencies in

> node_modules

directory. but dont know what is the next process and how to analyse repo to make it work in local. please help.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean by "how to analyse repo"? Anyways, the answer depends on what repo you're working on and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want to run the project cloned on your local? if yes then run `node src/server.js` and in browser go to url localhost:3000.

Comment: Thanks @vartika for the answer but i when i run `node src/server.js` it throws error  
import path from 'path';
^^^^^^

Comment: Can you tell me node version and npm version you are using? to check version run node -v & npm -v.

Comment: If `node` fails, then this is most likely not a git question.

Comment: Also be aware that the linked repoistory is outdated and its very README points you to: https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes-2

Comment: @vartika node -v => v6.9.5 , npm -v => v4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

From the wording in your question, it sounds like you may be confused between git and npm etc.

Git is a source control tool that is able to remotely/locally sync versioned files(changes).

Take a look at the following doc to learn about setting up a new git repo locally without a remote repo setup.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

NPM is a package manager for Node.JS

http://npmjs.com/

---

To see what others are doing with Git, go take a look at these and clone some: https://github.com/trending

Answer (score 0):

please run below command

git clone https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes.git

After that run 
npm install

Comment: I did it already and have installed all dependencies on node_modules folder. now i want to see project running on my browser.

Comment: now run project using npm run or starting scrip like : node server.js, node main.js